# How to schedule more than one job

Tags: etl, scheduler, jasperserver

could I please know. If I schedule 5 jobs, the first job settings appears in the contents of the generated file, the 1st and 2nd job settings appear in the second generated file, the 1st 2nd and 3rd job settings  appear in the 3rd file, the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th job settings  appear in the 4th file. Again the 1st 2nd 3rd 4th and 5th job settings  appear in the file.

The question is: Do I copy the contents of the last file only to the crontab configuration of my unix system since all the previous files contain basically the same information?

Rumbi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of only the last file will do